# What is "left-hand side of an assignment must be a 'x' variable

Tags: c#

why am I getting the error CS0131?

label1.Text = (Convert.ToString(label1) = "Potencia");

Comment: Can you provide the more context please?
And use Ctrl + K to highlight your code

Comment: Could you please clarify what value should be assigned to label.Text?

Answer (score 2):

In your case "left-hand side" is Convert.ToString(label1). And you are trying to assign value "Potencia" to Convert.ToString(label1) which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

That is not how you assign the value "Potencia" to your label

```
label1.Text = "Potencia";
```

Is this what you need?